# Is it possible to use geonodes output attribute in a different geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to use geonodes output attribute in a different geometry nodes?

For example, I want to use a certain index position value from a cube in a different geometry nodes applied to an sphere. Or any other way to do this?

Thanks!
Miguel

Comment: interesting q: I cannot use "Copy as new driver" on a geo output attribute, and if I create driver on a geo input, and use the object data path to a geo output, it doesn't seem to get the updated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *sample* the relevant information from another Geometry Nodes setup by bringing that object in via an `Object Info` node. You could inquire for the data directly, for instance like this:

[image]

The monkey has a simple GN setup which moves it on the *X* axis every second (bottom left). The Sphere has its own setup (on the right) which asks for the *Position* of the vertex #301 of the monkey, and moves the sphere there. Only the monkey is animated, but since that animation changes the *Position* continuously, the sphere moves with it.

Hard to imagine all possible scenarios without a tangible example, but if a stable geometry element (like our Vertex #301 here) to sample is not available somehow, a more generalized method could be to capture the relevant value with a `Store Named Attribute` node, and then sampling *that*:

[image]

Here, I'm storing a *Vector* value ($[2,2,2]$) on the vertices of the monkey with the name "*transfer*", then sampling specifically that `Named Attribute` to move the sphere. Since I captured the value on all points of the monkey, which *Index* number we're sampling here doesn't matter.